# Yii2 message extract yii category only

Tags: internationalization, yii2

I'm trying to get [i18n](/questions/tagged/i18n) of my Yii2 application. I have followed [an article's](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/programming-with-yii2-localization-with-i18n--cms-23140) instructions but it only extracts the message of "yii" category only. I could not able to make it to extract "app" category like those found in some string output such as:

```
\yii::t('app','Some message text');
```

What is the problem?

Comment: It should extract all categories and create a <category>.php file for it. Please post some extra information like your `messages/config.php`.

Comment: @Blizz I found that I have wrote translatable strings using `\yii::t` but `'translator'` key in the `i18n` conf has the value `Yii::t`. Indeed, setting the value as an array i.e `'translator' => ['\yii::t','yii::t','Yii::t'],` it extracted all strings in app.php. However, the translation does not work in the app after adding the `language` key in web.php config. By the way my message folder in `app/config/messages` where my language folder is there `ar`

Comment: For clarity I would always use `Yii::t()`, since the class is named like that. Even though yii::t is technically correct, imo it is confusing. You need to also [define the `i18n` component](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/tutorial-i18n.md#message-translation) in your configuration to tell Yii where to find the translations, just updating the `language` is not enough.

Comment: I found that the path of message that I have is not correct too. However, How could I translate `Not Found #404` I could not find it in the translatation files `yii.php`